# Retrieve totally different keys from Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use `orderByKey` for requesting data by keys from Firebase. I can get several objects if keys are similar — start or end with the same string.

But how can I retrieve totally different keys with one request to Firebase, e.g. "n:1-2-3" and "n:2-3-4"? I use `equalTo`, but can I specify more than one key there?

I know how to do it with different requests — one request per one key, but it's not optimal.

Comment: show a database sample example and explain more please, oh I think I understood you want more than one condition and no thats not possible. The most you can do is orderbykey().equalTo(key_here)

Comment: Ideologically, why can I request "animal_dog" and "animal_horse" with one request, but not "a123" and "a234"?

Comment: you can, u need to use startAt()

Comment: @PeterHaddad If I will use startAt("a") it will return me 1'000'000 results. I want to request only two "a123" and "a234".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently firebase only supports one condition. Explained more in the below text:-

If lets say you have two keys that are `a123` and `a234` then to retrieve you can do this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.orderByKey().startAt("a").limitToLast(10).addValueEventListener(..){..}
```

> The limitToLast() method is used to set a maximum number of children to be synced for a given callback

You can use limittolast or limittofirst, to limit the results that are obtained from the database.
Also currently firebase only supports one condition. So you cannot have more than one `orderbykey` or  `orderbychild` or the two together..

Comment: Problem is they are not last, I don't know order. E.g. "a123" has position 3453, "a234" has position 4357623. I can't use startAt() in my case. My initial question was: can I read totally different keys, e.g. "qwe" and "rty".

Comment: as in my answer I said, logically to read two different keys you do multiple conditions but since you can only do one condition then no you cannot, the max you can do is `orderBykey().equalto(onekeyhere)`

Comment: I can accept the answer if you put info like "currently firebase only supports one condition" at the beginning of the text. It will help other guys faster. Thanks.